# MongoDb ReplaceOne remove and insert new record or update?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have 2 services. Both are connected to the same mongodb.

Both use `ReplaceOne` method, and from time of time I get errors about duplicate key.

I think if `ReplaceOne` removes record and insert new - it explain my problem...

So... does method `ReplaceOne` remove record and insert new or update old record?

Comment: See if your service is not calling `ReplaceOne` with `upsert:true`.  see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.replaceOne/#behavior

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that perhaps your services are removing and inserting the new document at the same time when they are accessed simultaneously and generating with the same id.

I hope I have helped.